# Conditions with Typoscript for Fluidtemplates

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to add a fluidtemplate with the following code

```
[PIDupinRootline = 39] && [treeLevel = 4]
    lib.personSubMenuBack = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    lib.personSubMenuBack {
        file = EXT:sitepackage_my_domain/Resources/Private/TT_Address/Partials/PersonSubMenuBack.html
    }
[end]
```

In another fluidtemplate I added

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.personSubMenuBack" />
```

Now I get errors for the pages when the condition is wrong because '`lib.personSubMenuBack`' isn't found . To avoid this I added this before the condition

```
 lib.personSubMenuBack = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    lib.personSubMenuBack {
        file = EXT:sitepackage_my_domain/Resources/Private/TT_Address/Partials/PersonSubMenuEmpty.html

    }
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to solve the problem without an additional empty fluidtemplate `PersonSubMenuEmpty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[PIDupinRootline = 39] && [treeLevel = 4]
    lib.personSubMenuBack = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    lib.personSubMenuBack {
        file = EXT:sitepackage_my_domain/....
    }
[else]
    lib.personSubMenuBack = TEXT
[end]
```